# re-arrange my dataset by date and action of the lead

Tags: r, string

I'm working on R on a database that is structured in this way:

```
Lead      Date          state
1         01/01/2020    active
1         02/01/2020    standby
2         01/01/2020    standby
2         02/01/2020    active
2         03/01/2020    offer won
3         01/01/2020    standby
3         02/01/2020    active
...       ...           ...
```

And I want to have sth similar, that arranges the state of the lead using the date:

```
Lead     Chronology by date
1        active;standby
2        standby;active;offer won
3        standby;active
...      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is a data.frame named `df`, you can do this very easily with `tidyverse` packages.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  group_by(Lead) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  summarize(Chronology_by_date = str_c(state, collapse = ";"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option, which sort the rows using `order`, and then apply `aggregated` over rearranged data frame

```
aggregate(state~Lead,df[order(df$Lead,df$Date),],paste0,collapse = ";")
```